# How do I make an application autorun at login for all users?

Tags: autostart

How do I make an application autorun at login for all users? Im trying to have conky autorun for all users. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 64bit.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it... I had to write a script

`#!/bin/bash
sleep 5 && conky &`

the sleep 5 is to delay conky from starting always on top of all windows.

I named it conky_start.sh and placed it in /etc/profile.d

Answer (score 0):

I just got the startup applications menu back. I don't know specifically how I did it, but I believe it was when I install Ubuntu Tweaks. In any case I followed a few of the suggestions at these [two](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/04/things-to-tweak-after-installing-ubuntu.html) [pages](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/04/important-things-to-do-after-install_26.html). Hope this helps until someone else gives a more specific answer. Conky rocks!

Comment: Ive got the startup applications menu but that only works for the current user. I need it to work for all users.